# Adding multiple SHA256 hashes to Content Security Policy

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, security, webforms, content-security-policy

Genuinely can't find a resolution to this issue anywhere. Currently trying to add multiple SHA256 hashes to a Content Security Policy, like so:

```
default-src 'self' 'sha256-UITiqbXyaWS7NpwiFrMIbdXAZy5EXLRUHkpylF4504k=' 'sha256-0EZqoz+oBhx7gF4nvY2bSqoGyy4zLjNF+SDQXGp/ZrY=';
```

However, doing this seems to make no difference and just returns:

> Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>
> ```
> "default-src 'self' 'sha256-UITiqbXyaWS7NpwiFrMIbdXAZy5EXLRUHkpylF4504k=' 'sha256-0EZqoz+oBhx7gF4nvY2bSqoGyy4zLjNF+SDQXGp/ZrY='
> ```

Any idea how to add multiple hashes to this policy?

Already attempted to add multiple hashes delimited by spaces in their own single quotations marks under standard `default-src 'self'` policy. Only works if there's one hash, but want to add several.

Answer (score -2):

You policy syntax seems to be ok. I assume that the most likely reason for the behavior is:

1. Variations in the script code. Hashes will only work on static script code. If the code changes the hash will need to change, which means you will need to compute it dynamically and instert into CSP, move the variable out of script code or use a nonce.
2. Script event attributes such as "onClick". These can only be allowed with support for 'unsafe-hashes' in CSP level 3. Rewrite with an event handler.

Comment: I have the same problem with multiple hashes. Has the problem been solved?

Comment: Running into the same issue, the hashes are valid and exactly what Chrome is suggesting to add to the CSP, however, as soon as we add more than one sha to the script-src it doesn't register either of them.

Comment: Are they script attributes or script tags? Chrome lists the hashes for attributes even though they won't work unless you add 'unsafe-hashes', but that has a lot of other implications and it would be better to rewrite.